# send file to an api using guzzle http client

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

after uploading an image in web system a i want to push the image to another web system b.i am using guzzle http client to push and save the image in system b.i have been able to save the image in system a but when it reaches the part to push and save to system b an error that i have set to show when there is an error on uploading the image.here is my function to save the image on system a

```php
public function productSavePicture(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'product_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validation->fails()) {
            throw new \Exception("validation_error", 19);
        }
        $product_details = product::where('systemid', $request->product_id)->first();
        if (!$product_details) {
            throw new \Exception('product_not_found', 25);
        }
        if ($request->hasfile('file')) {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
            $company_id = Auth::user()->staff->company_id;
            if (!in_array($extension, array(
                'jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG', 'gif', 'GIF', 'bmp', 'BMP', 'tiff', 'TIFF'))) {
                return abort(403);
            }
            $filename = ('p' . sprintf("%010d", $product_details->id)) . '-m' . sprintf("%010d", $company_id) . rand(1000, 9999) . '.' . $extension;
            $product_id = $product_details->id;
            $this->check_location("/images/product/$product_id/");
            $file->move(public_path() . ("/images/product/$product_id/"), $filename);
            $this->check_location("/images/product/$product_id/thumb/");
            $thumb = new thumb();
            $dest = public_path() . "/images/product/$product_id/thumb/thumb_" . $filename;
            $thumb->createThumbnail(
                public_path() . "/images/product/$product_id/" . $filename,
                $dest,
                200);
            $systemid = $request->product_id;
            $product_details->photo_1 = $filename;
            $product_details->thumbnail_1 = 'thumb_' . $filename;
            $product_details->save();
            // push image to system on saving
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $url = "http://systemb/api/push_image";
            $response = $client->request('POST',$url,[
                'headers' => [ ],
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name'     => $filename,
                        'contents' => file_get_contents($product_details->getPath()),
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
        } else {
            return abort(403);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getMessage() == 'validation_error') {
            return '';
        }
        if ($e->getMessage() == 'product_not_found') {
            $msg = "Error occured while uploading, Invalid product selected";
        }
        {
            $msg = "Error occured while uploading picture";
        }
        $data = view('layouts.dialog', compact('msg'));
    }
    return $data;
}
```

i am getting the error "Error occured while uploading picture" but the error is saved in systema but its unabe to be pushed in systemb..i havent understood where i have gone wrong with my code base but i guess that part on guzzle isnt being executed because the data is being saved in systema but its unable to be pushed to systemb.what might be the issue here

Comment: Can I see this  `getPath()`?

Comment: In you catch exception you are overwriting the $msg in all cases to show always the message `$msg = "Error occured while uploading picture";` so in the end the error message doesnt inform you about the cause. you should change it to just `$msg = $e->getMessage()` and put it as the first statement in the catch part

Comment: @N69S works well but on changing i get an error "Call to undefined method App\Models\product::getPath()".

Comment: You do have or not the method `getPath()` in your Product::class model ? if not then why are you using it ? `file_get_contents($product_details->getPath())`

Comment: @N69S i learned about it somewhere but later i came to know it wasnt working

Comment: Then why are you using it ?  replace it with `file_get_contents(public_path() . "/images/product/$product_id/".$filename)`

Comment: it shows the image has been pushed  but it isnt saved in system b

Comment: cant help you without more details. have you tested the upload on the system b ? Have you confirmed that the url on the system b is indeed being called and what data is received ?

Comment: @N69S how can i mark your comment above as  the correct answer

Comment: @stephenWeru you cant accept a comment as the answer, added an answer below so you can close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class Product doesnt have the method getPath() declared

```
file_get_contents($product_details->getPath())
```

Change it so it uses the path you used above that line

```
file_get_contents(public_path() . "/images/product/$product_id/".$filename)
```